# Mount HDD to docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers, virtualization

I tried to use internal HDD in docker container. I have datasets in HDD to train AI model. And I want to train a model using with codes in container. I can not copy datasets to container because it is too large datasets. How can I connect them. Can I mount HDD, and can I use my datasets as input in container. Any suggestions?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the command

```
docker -v (directory of HDD):(directory inside container) <other options.. --name, {image Name} etc>
```

not working as expected?

The above command will reference the HDD at the directory inside the container you have provided without copying, so be catious about changes as they will be reflected in the HDD's data.

Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_storage.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I guess,  it should be <docker run -v (directory of HDD):(directory inside container) (image name)>. If you fix it, I can accept your answer. (If it is necessary.)

Comment: Actually, I was just mentioning the -v option. It was not intended to be the whole command, also along with the image name there are many other options present for docker (--name, -p ). So the answer would have been generalized.
I have made the required changes, you can accept it :)